# Execution doesn't go past the second fetch call (Gatsby related stuff)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fetch, gatsby

I am generating data for querying with gatsby's `sourceNodes` api.
The problem is that inside the `getHooksInfo` call something weird happens.
I do the first `await fetch(rawUrl)`(i am using node-fetch, but it doesn't matter that much)  request, everything's fine. But when i do the second request  `const res = await fetch(url)` inside `for (const guess of guesses)` it... does nothing. I see the first `console.log('before fetch');`, but not the `console.log('after fetch');`. No error either. It just goes straight to the return statement with result being always `[]`. I tried debugging, but debugger jumped to the return statement also on this line. Even stepping into the actual `fetch` call didn't help that much. So if you smell anything (besides the code, obviously;D ) here that leads to that behavior, i'd really appreciate your help.

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions;

   ...

  await Promise.allSettled(someArray
    .map(async ({ package: { links, author, description }, score, searchScore }, i) => {
      const { npm, homepage, repository } = links;
      const { final, detail: { popularity } } = score;

      const { ok, result } = await getHooksInfo(repository);

   ...
      createNode(...);
    }));
```

```
async function getHooksInfo(repository) {
  ...
  const res = await fetch(rawUrl);

  if (!res.ok) {
    return {
      ok: false,
      result: null
    };
  }

  const readme = await res.text();
  const hooks = [...];

  const result = [];

  await Promise.allSettled(
    hooks.map(async (hook) => {
      for (const guess of guesses) {
        ...

        console.log('before fetch');
        const res = await fetch(someUrl);
        console.log('after fetch');
        ...
      }

    })
  );

  return {
    ok: true,
    result
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `Promise.allSettled` is swallowing some syntax error in your `fetch(url)` and that that is why you aren't getting errors.

Comment: fair point, but try catch'ing doesn't yield anything helpful (it doesn't throw)

Comment: I'm not familiar with how `for..of` loops work internally, but if they are function-like then `await` can't be used in them, because they are synchronous. Try `urls.forEach(async (url) => {await fetch(url); })`.